# windows 10 start menu tile icons - shows only in one screen

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

My main screen eventually shows no tile icons when I open the start menu. This is quite known for Windows 10, as seen in many questions here and throughout the web.

The weird thing that I discovered accidentally though was that opening the start menu from my secondary screen, not only the icons shows it right, but the icons from the main screen are also temporalily fixed!

I was hoping someone could explain why this happens?

Comment: Have you gone through the steps outlined in the posts elsewhere regarding this issue? Mainly these are the standard Windows 10 repair options.

Comment: @music2myear yes, I'm just trying to understand why

Comment: We won't be able to begin to guess "why" until we've ascertained the solution. The solution is based on the reason for the problem, so knowing what fixes the problem may help us understand why the problem occurred. HOWEVER, this site's strength is in answering the first part. We don't usually trouble ourselves with understanding the "why" because even IF we know the solution, there are still going to be countless myriad of reasons that may lead to each possible solution. So, do you want us to solve your problem, or do you just want to understand why your problem is occurring?